# Any Resources for Micro Comprehensive Exams?

Tags: microeconomics

I'm currently preparing for a first year microeconomics comprehensive exam and have been looking for good resources for a while. Ideally, I was looking for any school site that has a list of (and links to) their old micro comps with solutions.

We cover what I'd imagine is a pretty standard course- a half semester each on partial equilibrium, general equilibrium, social choice and game theory; though all that's needed is any overlap between those and whatever the other school's comp covers.

Again, sorry if this isn't the right place, but if anyone has any sources off-hand, I'd very much appreciate it!

Comment: Google "econ 101 exercises slides pdf" or related (like subtopics), and you get a lot of sites of professors/teachers apparently willing to share their material with the world (e.g. [here](http://homepages.stmartin.edu/fac_staff/dstout/ECN101/internet_exercises.htm) or [here](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~gwallace/ECON_101/Homework/homework.htm)).

Comment: @luchonacho "Comprehensive Exams" usually refers to the examined coursework component of a US PhD, not to econ 101 level material. AndrewC: did you take a look at the exercises in Varian's Microeconomic Analysis? My prior is they will be much closer to the comps at your institution than, say, the exercises in Mas-Colell et al. You should be able to find the solution manual floating around somewhere.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Thanks for the clarification! Never heard of that terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I know Harvard posts its past comprehensive exams: https://economics.harvard.edu/pages/past-general-exams. I imagine many other schools would have such resources available to the public as well. You'd just have to do a little bit of Googling to find out.

However, I doubt that any of these past exam questions would have solutions available (and they should not be). You should try the questions on your own. If you're stuck, discuss the issues with your classmates/friends/professors. You're also welcome to ask questions here, but be sure to following our [policy on homework questions](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions) and the [general guidelines of this site](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thank you very much for the resource! I'm going through and trying to find other schools' as well now.

The reason I initially was hoping for solutions as well was mostly to double check that I fully answer each question. Often, I've found my downfall is in finding (for example) 3 of the Bayesian equilibria of a game when there are actually 4- something that's hard to notice unless it's pointed out. Same thing goes with finding the entire PE set in an Edgeworth Box (I have a bad habit of leaving parts of it out, for no clear reason haha). But thank you very much for the link!!