# PhD Micro and Macro Comprehensive Exams

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, academic-graduate

I am interested in seeing some old examples of PhD comprehensive exams in both Micro and Macro. I have seen that previous posts ([like this one](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/16898/any-resources-for-micro-comprehensive-exams)) had some suggestions given, but some of the links (such as one from Harvard) do not work anymore.

I know that some schools give their current PhD students studying for the comps older versions from an archive but these tend to be given with the understanding that they are not to be shared. In any case I thought I would try my luck here :)

Thanks for any and all suggestions!

Comment: Just a heads up, if you're hoping to find them as resources to your own exams, they will not be very helpful!

Comment: Why is that? Im mostly just using them for practice/ exposure to higher level problems :)

Comment: In my experience the questions will be made by your own professors, and thus everyone has their own style of questions asked. Of course, don't let me stop you from pursuing other exams if you feel it would be helpful! (Going over old comp from your own department will be the most helpful imo).

Comment: It’s not about solving standard problems. The point is testing if you have understood the deep logic and have the capability to do research. As I’ve experienced, the questions in qualifying exam are mostly based on the simplified versions of models from recent papers (especially macro). Prof will split the derivation into small parts and guide you to replicate the whole model by yourself.

Comment: Oh that's interesting! Perhaps then the best way to study is to pick relevant models that are most common, take the initial assumptions/ conditions and then try to  derive the whole model from first principles?